# Mongod resident memory usage low

Tags: mongodb, memory

I'm trying to debug some performance issues with a MongoDB configuration, and I noticed that the resident memory usage is sitting very low (around 25% of the system memory) despite the fact that there are occasionally large numbers of faults occurring.  I'm surprised to see the usage so low given that MongoDB is so memory dependent.

Here's a snapshot of top sorted by memory usage.  It can be seen that no other process is using an significant memory:

```
top - 21:00:47 up 136 days,  2:45,  1 user,  load average: 1.35, 1.51, 0.83
Tasks:  62 total,   1 running,  61 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.7%us,  5.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 77.3%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  2.4%st
Mem:   1692600k total,  1676900k used,    15700k free,    12092k buffers
Swap:   917500k total,    54088k used,   863412k free,  1473148k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2461 mongodb   20   0 29.5g 564m 492m S 22.6 34.2  40947:09 mongod
20306 ubuntu    20   0 24864 7412 1712 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.76 bash
20157 root      20   0 73352 3576 2772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 sshd
  609 syslog    20   0  248m 3240  520 S  0.0  0.2  38:31.35 rsyslogd
20304 ubuntu    20   0 73352 1668  872 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
    1 root      20   0 24312 1448  708 S  0.0  0.1   0:08.71 init
20442 ubuntu    20   0 17308 1232  944 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.54 top
```

I'd like to at least understand why the memory isn't being better utilized by the server, and ideally to learn how to optimize either the server config or queries to improve performance.

UPDATE:
It's fair that the memory usage looks high, which might lead to the conclusion it's another process.  There's no other processes using any significant memory on the server; the memory appears to be consumed in the cache, but I'm not clear why that would be the case:

```
$free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1652       1602         50          0         14       1415
-/+ buffers/cache:        172       1480
Swap:          895         53        842
```

UPDATE:
You can see that the database is still page faulting:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults       locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn   set repl       time
     0    402    377      0    1167     446       0  24.2g  51.4g     3g      0  <redacted>:9.7%          0       0|0     1|0   217k   420k   457 mover  PRI   03:58:43
    10    295    323      0     961     592       0  24.2g  51.4g  3.01g      0 <redacted>:10.9%          0      14|0     1|1   228k   500k   485 mover  PRI   03:58:44
    10    240    220      0     698     342       0  24.2g  51.4g  3.02g      5 <redacted>:10.4%          0       0|0     0|0   164k   429k   478 mover  PRI   03:58:45
    25    449    359      0     981     479       0  24.2g  51.4g  3.02g     32 <redacted>:20.2%          0       0|0     0|0   237k   503k   479 mover  PRI   03:58:46
    18    469    337      0     958     466       0  24.2g  51.4g     3g     29 <redacted>:20.1%          0       0|0     0|0   223k   500k   490 mover  PRI   03:58:47
     9    306    238      1     759     325       0  24.2g  51.4g  2.99g     18 <redacted>:10.8%          0       6|0     1|0   154k   321k   495 mover  PRI   03:58:48
     6    301    236      1     765     325       0  24.2g  51.4g  2.99g     20 <redacted>:11.0%          0       0|0     0|0   156k   344k   501 mover  PRI   03:58:49
    11    397    318      0     995     395       0  24.2g  51.4g  2.98g     21 <redacted>:13.4%          0       0|0     0|0   198k   424k   507 mover  PRI   03:58:50
    10    544    428      0    1237     532       0  24.2g  51.4g  2.99g     13 <redacted>:15.4%          0       0|0     0|0   262k   571k   513 mover  PRI   03:58:51
     5    291    264      0     878     335       0  24.2g  51.4g  2.98g     11  <redacted>:9.8%          0       0|0     0|0   163k   330k   513 mover  PRI   03:58:52
```

Comment: I guess some other process is using up memory. Check `Mem:   1692600k total,  1665384k used,    27216k free`

Comment: No other process is using memory, but the cache usage is high.  See update to the question.

Comment: If you are talking about swap cache, then MongoDB doesn't uses swap `http://goo.gl/VwNdqp`. As per I can see, the total used 'Mem' is 1665384k in which mongodb is utilizing only 23.3%. The buffer(Mem) size is also not very high. There has to be some process which is making Mem (used) to 1665384k

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I've updated the top dump to show the top memory consumers on the server.  Since you're saying that Mongo is not using the memory, how would I determine which process is, seeing that top is showing no other memory usage.

Comment: buffers & cache is something, OS caches for the other processes,to run fast. So, if `mongod` is the only process running in the box, you can be sure that the cache files mostly are MongoDB data files. If this MongoDB is not in production, you can use this tool `https://github.com/10gen-labs/storage-viz` to check details about the pages that are cached in RAM. Rest there is already 1 answer posted in which You can try `touch` and `mongostat` command. According to me though RA doesn't affect effectiveness of memory utilization but has other consequences and most of the time should be low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this was being caused by a large amount of inactive memory on the server that wasn't be cleared for Mongo's use.

By looking at the result from:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

I could see a large amount of Inactive memory.  Using this command as a sudo user:

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && echo "" && free
```

Freed up the inactive memory, and over the next 24 hours I was able to see the resident memory of my Mongo instance increasing to consume the rest of the memory available on the server.

Credit to the following blog post for it's instructions:

http://tinylan.com/index.php/article/how-to-clear-inactive-memory-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only uses as much memory as it needs, so if all of the data and indexes that are in MongoDB can fit inside what it's currently using you won't be able to push that anymore.

If the data set is larger than memory, there are a couple of considerations:

- Check MongoDB itself to see how much data it thinks its using by running [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) and looking at resident-memory
- Was MongoDB re/started recently? If it's cold then the data won't be in memory until it gets paged in (leading to more page faults initially that gradually settle). Check out the [touch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) command for more information on "warming MongoDB up"
- Check your read ahead settings. If your system read ahead is too high then MongoDB can't efficiently use the memory on the system. For MongoDB a good number to start with is a setting of 32 (that's 16 KB of read ahead assuming you have 512 byte blocks)

Comment: Mongostat reflects what is seen here with it's resident memory values.  Uptime on the server is 3834510, so I believe it should be stable.  The read ahead settings *were*, however, set to 256. I've reduced them to 32, and will monitor if I see any change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: Windows Server 2008 R2, 16 Gb RAM, Mongo 2.4.3. Mongo uses only 2 Gb of RAM and generates a lot of page faults. Queries are very slow. Disk is idle, memory is free. Found no other solution than upgrade to 2.6.5. It helped.